# Ant JUnit not showing failed test details

Tags: junit, ant, ant-junit

I am using Ant version 1.9.7 and JUnit 4.12. My build.xml looks like this:

```
<target name="run-junit" depends="init, compile, compile-junit">
    <junit printsummary="yes" >
        <formatter type="xml"/>
        <classpath><pathelement location="lib/junit-4.12.jar"/></classpath>
        <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${out.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${bin.dir}">
                <include name="**/*Test.class"/>
            </fileset>
        </batchtest>
    </junit>
</target>
```

When running `ant run-junit` in a console it just gives me:

```
[junit] Running at.abc.def.ghi.ABCTest
[junit] Tests run: 5, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.065 sec
Test at.abc.def.ghi.ABCTest FAILED
```

But no more details. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get more details about each failed test, use `<formatter type="plain" usefile="false"/>` instead of  `<formatter type="xml"/>`:

```
<junit printsummary="yes">
    <formatter type="plain" usefile="false"/>
    <classpath><pathelement location="lib/junit-4.12.jar"/></classpath>
    <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${out.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${bin.dir}">
            <include name="**/*Test.class"/>
        </fileset>
    </batchtest>
</junit>
```

Using a "plain" formatter gives output similar to the following:

```
[junit] Running TestMyTest1
[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.014 sec
[junit]
[junit] Testcase: testMyTest took 0.003 sec
[junit]     FAILED
[junit] expected:<firefox> but was:<null>
[junit] junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<firefox> but was:<null>
[junit]     at TestMyTest1.testMyTest(TestMyTest1.java:17)
[junit]
[junit] Test TestMyTest1 FAILED
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this! Is it possible to have both?

Comment: @今天春天 Yes, `<junit>` accepts multiple `<formatter>` elements.